# Answer to question on bounty incomplete

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I put a [question on stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400935/how-do-i-refresh-recurring-reminders-in-ios-reminders-app-when-they-stop-remindi) on bounty and got a good answer to which I awarded the bounty, but the answer is incomplete. I still don't have a complete solution. The answer that won the bounty gave me the solution to fix the problem so that the Reminders are current as shown in the Reminders app, but the Reminders still won't fire. None of the Reminders on the iOS device used fires. What should I do to get more complete answers?

Answer (score 7):

Ask another question about the specific issue you have left. Show where you've got to by putting your updated code in that question.

A bounty isn't a guarantee of a complete answer, or even any answer at all. Think of it more like paying for an advert in a newspaper. You might get what you want, you might not. In your case, at least you got something out of it.

Answer (score 5):

To get a more complete answer, it's necessary to compose a complete question.

There is never a guarantee that you will get any answer at all. An answer can only be as good as the information provided in a question enables it to be (sufficient to understand what's being asked and providing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where appropriate).

I'd say that the answer does reflect the amount of research, effort and understanding that went into the question. Generally, this type of question gets closed as "too broad" or "off-topic" because there's no code provided that shows how the problem developed and how it can be reproduced. You might want to review the site guidelines for effectively asking questions in the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

A bounty having been set will have prevented the question from being closed at the time it was posted. But please keep in mind that the experts who assist here do so *voluntarily*. Indeed, anyone who posts an answer does so voluntarily, whether an "expert" or someone with less experience in a technology; whether a long-time Stack Overflow participant or someone new to the site. Considered from that perspective, it's important to *motivate* others to *want* to answer a question - rather than *expect* them to put in the work to answer.

As often stated, Stack Overflow is neither a tutorial site, nor a free coding service. The quality and effort of answers generally reflects that put into composing a question.

Note that you don't *have* to accept any answer as "the" answer and award the bounty if you find the answer incomplete.

Comment: Just +42 for this sentence alone: *I'd say that the answer does reflect the amount of research, effort and understanding that went into the question.*

Comment: *slow....clap* You have made my day with this response.